# Replace column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this table,

```
Name       Rating
A            2
B            1 
C            5
D            3
E            1
F            4
```

and I've got a rating system

```
1-Excellent, 2-Very Good, 3-Good, 4-OK, 5-Poor
```

I was wondering if i could replace the nueric values in the table to get the following result table.

```
Name       Rating
A         Very Good
B         Excellent
C           Poor
D           Good
E         Excellent
F            OK
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have Excellent 2 times?

Comment: @sidux He edited the question. Your comment makes no sense anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement.  Of course, this will only work if your column is not set to a numeric value.

```
UPDATE tblRatings
SET Rating = CASE WHEN 1 THEN 'Excellent'
                  WHEN 2 THEN 'Very Good'
                  WHEN 3 THEN 'Good'
                  WHEN 4 THEN 'OK'
                  ELSE 'Poor' 
             END
```

If it is, you'll need to use a `SELECT` statement;

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 THEN 'Excellent'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Very Good'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Good'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'OK'
            ELSE 'Poor' 
       END
  FROM tblRatings
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's good idea to update your data inplace, it's better to store id of the rating and not text representation of the data. But you can query your table and replace int with text:

```
select
    Name,
    case Rating
        when 1 then 'Excellent'
        when 2 then 'Very Good,'
        when 3 then 'Good'
        when 4 then 'OK'
        when 5 then 'Poor'
    end as Rating
from <your table>
```

Or you can create a lookup table and join with it

```
create table Rating (id int, desc nvarchar(128))

insert into Rating (id, desc)
select 1, 'Excellent' union all
select 2, 'Very good' union all
select 3, 'Good' union all
select 4, 'OK' union all
select 5, 'Poor'

select
    t.Name,
    R.desc as Rating
from <your table> as t
    left outer join Rating as R on R.id = t.Rating
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Choose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213019.aspx)

IF `sql-server 2012`

like this:

```
 select Rating,name,choose(Rating,'Excellent','Very Good','Good','OK','Excellent','Poor') from table
```

<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/feed9/1)</kbd>

Comment: Well,I dont see any `Tags` ! but yes should have mentioned `sql-server 2012` thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use update function :

```
update yourtable set rating = 'Excellent' where rating = '1'
```

and zou can do this update for all your ratings

Comment: He writes that rating is **numeric**! Your answer will not work!

Answer (score -1):

```
Update YOURTABLE

set Rating = case when '2' then ' Very good'
            when '3' then ' good' end
```

Comment: He writes that rating is **numeric**! Your answer will not work!