# Making an array out of substr_replace

Tags: php

Hi everyone newbie here,

I'm taking on the tedious task of changing a bunch of IDs for a game and turning them into a string. As you can see here I do this for ID 29 and turn it into Sharpshooter. Is there a more efficient way for me to do this? Or am i stuck writing about 100 more if cases?

```
    if ($rows[1] == 29)
    {
        $rows[1] = substr_replace("29","Sharpshooter",0); 
    }
```

Below is my full code and I have added a few more examples of what I'm talking about.

```
<?php

/* Link DB */
include_once 'config.php';

/* Initialize Connection */
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $conn_array);
if ($conn){
}else{
    die; 
}

/* Prepare Statement Preparation */
$sql = "
SELECT TOP 25 G.CharacterName, G.JobCode, D.PVPWin, D.PVPLose, G.PvPExp, D.PVPGiveUp
FROM PvPRanking as G
INNER JOIN PVPScores as D
ON G.CharacterID = D.CharacterID
ORDER BY  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalRank ASC ) 
";

/* Assign Parameter values. */
$param1 = 1;
$param2 = 2;

// Array requirement for prepare statement.
$procedure_params = array(
    array(&$param1, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
    array(&$param2, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
);

/* The ACTUAL Prepare Statement */
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, $procedure_params);

/*Execute*/
sqlsrv_execute($stmt);


/* Variables */
$autoincrement = 0;

echo

'
<tr>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Class</th>
<th>Wins</th>
<!-- <th>Losses</th>
<th>Experience</th>
<th>Quit</th> -->
</tr>';

// Rank # to increment itself. I.E 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc..
while ($rows=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
{
    $autoincrement++;
{
    if ($rows[1] == 29)
    {
        $rows[1] = substr_replace("29","Sharpshooter",0); 
    }
    if ($rows[1] == 30)
    {
        $rows[1] = substr_replace("30","Knight",0); 
    }
    if ($rows[1] == 29)
    {
        $rows[1] = substr_replace("31","Dragon Slayer",0); 
    }

}

// Echo will spit out the rows and the data.
echo 

'
<tr id=io>
<td> '.$autoincrement.' </td>
<b> <td style = "color:#AFA;"> '.$rows[0].' </td> </b>
<td> '.$rows[1].' </td>
<td> '.$rows[2].' </td>
<!--  <td> '.$rows[3].' </td>
<td> '.$rows[4].' </td>
<td> '.$rows[5].' </td> -->
';  


}
 ?>




</table>
```

Comment: I have taken a look at other posts, but I haven't seen one with an if condition specified like mine. The examples I found were people replacing every instance of an integer or string with their variable. I have updated my post showing more of my code and a few more examples.

Comment: `Is there a more efficient way for me to do this?` ... Create a helper data file, make it space or comma or tab delimited for example. In one column put the ID, in the 2nd column put the name. Then write a short script that translates that to PHP code that defines your `$replacements` in the @mickmackusa sense below. Copy and paste that code generation result to your source.

Comment: @Get Stack Overflow does not want you to comment solutions.  I have extended my answer to advise a new column in the database to JOIN to.  This will be better than managing a lookup file.

Comment: Noted @mickmackusa. My bad. I was under the impression that the game was being "ported". I misread or assumed much. Why would that be relevant? Because then I could not provide a solution with incomplete code source, only ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own translation array.  If the value is not a key in the array, do not replace it.

```
$replacements = [
    29 => 'Sharpshooter',
];

$rows[1] = $replacements[$rows[1]] ?? $rows[1];
```

Assuming you are using a loop, the translation array should be written before the loop.

Alternatively, this could all be executed in the sql with [a CASE block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29277415/2943403).

---

**Ultimately, I would advise you to avoid performing this operation on every call of your query.**  You should simply add these translations as a new column in PvPRanking (or where most appropriate) and add them to the result set. In other words, whatever table has the `JobCode` values listed as unique values -- that table should receive the new column.

If you DON'T have a table that contains these unique jobcodes, then you should make one and join that table to your existing query.  This is the most professional and maintainable solution because when you need to update the list, you only need to update the table instead of potentially multuple files in your project.

Comment: Thanks I should've mentioned sooner I was using a loop. My apologies and thank you for the guidance. Will accept answer ASAP.

Comment: Added better advice.

Comment: Just saw this update. Yeah I was thinking it may be better to have these accessible in the database for easier use later on too. Thanks for the advice, I will be implementing this idea

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you are passing parameters to your prepared statement. You don't even need a prepared statement, since you are not passing any patameters to it. Do not add `<b>` tags outside of `<td>`. In fact, just use css instead.  You have too many curly braces in your loop.

Comment: Honestly I'm really new. I have nothing to input to this prepared statement, but I couldn't get this to work without inputting some sort of param